# Can I get a Google Apps for Work Collaborative Inbox into a mail client?

Tags: email, google-groups, google-apps-for-work

I have set up a collaborative inbox for a customer using Google Apps for Work, through the Google Groups for Business App. I want to know if it's possible to get this email address to work in a mail client (Mac Mail / Outlook etc.) in the same way as a Google Apps for Work user account (or indeed any other email address).

Is this at all possible? I'm that guessing since this email address is really a Google Group, and not an email address in the traditional sense, that it cannot be accessed through IMAP or POP.